# How to add UITableView in a customize view declared dynamically in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

In my app,in navigation bar one button (say **browsebutton**) is there , as i click the button one view (say **browseView**) appears which I took dynamically with the help of CGRectMake function.

I added UITableView (say **browseTableView**) in the  browseView.

Table gets added to the browseView but the delegate methods are not working.

Please give me proper direction.

My code is as follows:

### MainViewController.h

```
@interface MainViewController : UIMainViewController <UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>
```

### MainViewController.m

```
browseTableView.delegate = self;
browseTableView.dataSource =self;

-(void)BrowseButton {

    browseView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 300.0, 500.0)];
    browseView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    browseView.opaque = NO;
    [browseView.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
    [browseView.layer setBorderWidth: 4.0];
    [browseView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    browseTableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 300, 460)];
    [browseView addSubview:browseTableView];
    [self.view addSubview:browseView];      
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    categoryArray =  [[NSMutableArrayalloc]initWithObjects:@"Platinum",@"Diamond",
    @"Gold",@"Silver", nil];
    return [categoryArray count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]init];
    cell.textLabel.text = [categoryArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: It is hard to point you in the right direction when we don't know where you are going. Please state what you are trying to achieve and what you are trying to get the app to do. This question is a little vague in that respect. You also state that the "delegate methods are not working", please explain how exactly and why you came to that conclusion

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to mention:

```
browseTableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 300, 460)];
browseTableView.delegate = self;
browseTableView.dataSource = self;
[browseView addSubview:browseTableView];
```

Comment: You need to set it after  browseTableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 300, 460)]; beacause you create a new object and it's overriten.

Comment: if i add table to main view its getting added

Comment: but m not able to add it in that browseview itself.

Comment: it's pretty strange, it should get added. Can you share the project or a demo so I can try it out?